# Off topic does not allow choosing Open Data SE?

Tags: support, status-completed

I recently voted to close [Norway historic data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260087) as I personally felt it was off topic and more ideally suited for the Open Data SE site. When I chose close, then off topic and then the option that it is for another part of the SE network I was offered up only the GIS meta SE site.  I don't know if this is a bug? I would have thought if you are explicitly stating it is for another part of the SE network you would have been given the choice to select one or at least not forced to lump it into the meta site as that would have been wholly inappropriate.

Am I missing something? Does GIS SE think that if it is flagged as off topic then by default they are all meta questions?

Comment: This has been asked a few times - the Migrate close option *only* offers Meta (except to Moderators).  The correct close option would be *Questions relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here but can be researched/asked at Stack Overflow (software development), Super User (computing hardware and software), Database Administrators (relational databases) and other SE sites*.  If you feel it **must** be migrated, then flag for moderator and explain to the moderator why it has to be migrated.

Comment: Additionally, GIS SE Moderators *cannot* change the list of Migrate sites - it has to be done through Meta SE request and convince SE staff that it is needed.

Comment: @Midavalo Ah! I did search meta to see if this question had been asked before, but I clearly failed to choose the right search words! Thanks for point me in the right direction. Seems like whuber's reply suggest the underlying reason why it does not exist, it will upset too many other parts of the SE network.

Comment: Many SE sites do have migrate options, but I get the feeling it isn't well liked particularly by many of the receiving sites (the main one being [so]), and there are technical issues around what happens when the migrated message is closed or deleted etc. - it's safer to close as off-topic and then have the asker re-ask on another site.

Comment: An enhancement to migration that could do with more support has started to be discussed at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186461/215590